# What is special about valley-focused Hamiltonians that make them give quantized/rational (valley) Chern numbers?

Tags: mathematical-modeling, model-hamiltonians, berry-phase, valleytronics, topological-matter

I have been thinking about so-called valley Chern numbers $C_v$ and associated topological phenomena. To my knowledge, they are usually applicable when inter-valley scattering is suppressed, leaving the Berry curvature peaked at a high symmetry point ($K,K',\Gamma,M,...$). Following are few of several examples involving such Hamiltonians:

- [Zhang, Fan, Allan H. MacDonald, and Eugene J. Mele. "Valley Chern numbers and boundary modes in gapped bilayer graphene." Proceedings of the National Academy of Sciences 110.26 (2013): 10546-10551](https://www.pnas.org/content/110/26/10546)
- [Qiao, Zhenhua, et al. "Topological phases in gated bilayer graphene: Effects of Rashba spin-orbit coupling and exchange field." Physical Review B 87.12 (2013): 125405](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.87.125405)

In theoretical models, people usually use Hamiltonians (sometimes starting from lattice Hamiltonians), to derive a $k\cdot p$ Hamiltonian that is centered at the $K$ point. Then, they sum the Berry curvature of filled bands in the limit $k\rightarrow \infty$ (usually a very large $k$-space numerically) to get the Chern number at each valley $C_K,C_{K'}$. This is then used to calculate $C_v=C_K - C_{K'}$. Numerically, $C_K$ are oftentimes not perfectly quantized, but are very close (ex: $0.999 \rightarrow 1$).

On top of models like these, there are lattice models ([such as Haldane's model for the QAHE](https://journals.aps.org/prl/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevLett.61.2015)), that can yield similar quantized results. In these cases, one could do a low-energy expansion at the $K$ point to potentially [see something similar](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.85.165456) (idea of 'topological charge').

**My confusion is:** What makes these valley-type Hamiltonians special enough to give quantized Chern numbers in these limits? I am used to thinking of topological quantities as properties of the entire Bruillouin zone (ex: Chern number of QAHE), half-Brillouin zone (ex: $\mathbb{Z}_2$ index), or just a loop around gapless points (ex: $\pi$-phase in graphene). So, what makes these valley-type Hamiltonians correctly give the same/accurate information about topological phenomena even though they are simpler and localized to special points? I think that $k\cdot p$ models are diagonal at the $K$ point, and off-diagonals kick in as we move farther away from the chosen point. While I think that some information is lost (not sure what exactly), perhaps there might be some special symmetry that isn't lost? I am not convinced that all this is due to ***potential*** linear Dirac dispersions...

**I am asking because I messed around with some $k$-space effective Hamiltonians derived from DFT calculations, and they don't seem to behave as nicely/quantizedly compared to aforementioned theoretical/lattice/$k\cdot p$ models.** Perhaps, this question might also be related to the question of how a $k\cdot p$ Hamiltonian about a high-symmetry/$K$ point might reflect valley topology accurately whereas a fictitious $k\cdot p$ Hamiltonian about a faraway, non-special, "low-symmetry point" might not.

I apologize this question might not have been phrased properly, but I appreciate your patience.

Comment: In these systems, are there other degenerate or non-degenerate points? Generally, the Berry curvature peaks near band crossings and avoided crossings. Symmetry often enforces crossings at high-symmetry points.

Comment: @Anyon, it's usually been only $K$ and $K'$ (with potential band crossings). However, some models (ex: monolayer $MoS_2$ model using a $3d$ orbital basis) have Berry curvature peaked at the $\Gamma$ point even without crossings. That said, do you have any (ideally not-too-difficult) resources to recommend, that explain the idea of Berry curvature peaking near (band/avoided) crossings? I mean, I see why this would be the case due to the energy denominator ($E_n-E_m$; for bands $n,m$), but I think it can peak due to non-energy-related Hamiltonian parameters/wavefunctions as well.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't really have such a resource, but you basically have the argument already - small energy differences in the denominator can cause large $\Omega$. The opposite perspective is to look for regions where the wave function (or properties) vary rapidly with $\mathbf{k}$. Often that occurs where the gap is small ([example](https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.74.195118)), but you're probably correct that it's not necessarily the case.

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned. It can be reopened if OP returns and addresses questions/suggestions from the comments.